# Access denied executing compiled program

Tags: windows, go

Using Windows, my Hello World code is in `src\hello\hello.go`.

When using the command "go run hello.go"
Getting Error like this

```
# command-line-arguments


C:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: cannot create $WORK\b001\exe\a.out.exe: open $WORK\b001\exe\a.out.exe: Access is denied.
```

Comment: What value has $WORK?

Comment: The error says it is trying to write to  a folder called "$WORK". This probably is an invalid path.

Could you share the output of `go env` ?

Comment: $WORK may be an environment variable. And may be replaced by its content

Comment: Upvoting the question back to zero, because the answers are useful.

Answer (score 4):

This can be caused by an anti-virus application like AVG or G-Data.

You can use the `-o` argument with `go run` to specify the output directory, and add that path to the exclude list of your anti-virus should this be the cause.

Comment: Is the error in your question accurate? Because "$WORK" is not a valid path or variable on Windows.
Are you executing `go run` from a command prompt, Powershell, or something like Cygwin?


Have you tried `go run -o %USERPROFILE%\Desktop hello.go` ?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the executable is being edited in some way, or currently running. Check if you have any spare processes of this executable, or in the worst case, try restarting your computer.

Alternatively, it may also be that the linker genuinely does not have write access to the output directory. Make sure that the directory is writable to the user you are compiling your program as.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  code folder to the exception list solved the problem.

**Windows Security-> Virus and Threat Protection Settings -> Exclutions->Add folder**

Add your workplace folder here where your code exists. Adding temp folder didn't work for me.

```
go build gotest.go ; .\gotest.exe
```

Using the above command (regular command prompt.) can eliminate pop-up alerts but don't know the reason.